# Render CefSharp Offscreen Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, render, cefsharp

I currently have the problem to display a OffScreen Control in a WPF context.
I could use the WPF control given by cefsharp, but the problem is that the control only gets initialized when drawable (which is a problem).

Rendering a image is no big deal, but want to display a series of images (no high framerates is needed), also should it not eat the whole performance on the computer while doing this.

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: What is your question?. I'll point out that you can call Arrange manually and start the rendering process. You can also implement your own version of the WPF control, all the core parts are publicly accessible

Comment: I want to display the browser, without interaction by the user. Adapting the WPF Control is currently a problem, as I cant compile CefSharp, but this is a different topic.

Comment: You don't need to compile from source, you can still use the WPF NuGet package and create your own custom class similar to ChromiumWebBrowser. Using the OffScreen version is possible though I'd personally go with the option I've outlined. Best of luck